# CSS @ in Kotlin CSS

Tags: css, kotlin, ktor

Hey how can I implement css parts like the following in Kotlin CSS Builder?

```
@media (min-width: 991.98px) {
  main {
    padding-left: 240px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```kotlin
media("(min-width: 991.98px)") {
    rule("main") {
        paddingLeft = 240.px
    }
}
```